# Type error while trying to put all values from keys to list

Tags: json, python-3.x

Im trying to parse some Json data, I have almost been able to get all of it but I've been getting some errors in the last steps.

Here is the data I have.

```
{
    "data": {
        "__type": {
            "fields": [
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                            "name": "ID"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "displayName",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                            "name": "String"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "isAdmin",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                            "name": "Boolean"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "isDesigner",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                            "name": "Boolean"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "isSystem",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                            "name": "Boolean"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "responsiveness",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                            "name": "Int"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "profile",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "OBJECT",
                            "name": "Profile"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "designerLevel",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "ENUM",
                            "name": "DesignerLevel"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "fullName",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                            "name": "String"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "email",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                            "name": "String"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "timezone",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                            "name": "String"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "penaltyState",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "ENUM",
                            "name": "PenaltyState"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "languages",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "LIST",
                            "name": null
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "address",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "OBJECT",
                        "ofType": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "urlToken",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                            "name": "String"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "phoneNumber",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "SCALAR",
                        "ofType": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "phoneCountry",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "SCALAR",
                        "ofType": null
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "verificationStatus",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                            "name": "String"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "notificationSettings",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "OBJECT",
                            "name": "NotificationSettings"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "emailUnsubscribeHash",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                            "name": "String"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "isOnline",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                            "name": "Boolean"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "isPartnershipDesigner",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                            "name": "Boolean"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "name": "signedCodeOfConduct",
                    "type": {
                        "kind": "NON_NULL",
                        "ofType": {
                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                            "name": "Boolean"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I got every name, for example, by doing something like the following:

```
specificTypeJson = (json.loads(specificTypeResponse.text))

specificType_name = [f['name'] for f in specificTypeJson['data']['__type']['fields']]
```

I was also able to get the `kind` from inside `type` but the problem comes when I try to get `kind` from `ofType` which is inside `type`.

Im doing the following:

```
specificType_type_ofType_kinds = [f['type']['ofType']['kind'] for f in specificTypeJson['data']['__type']['fields']]
```

But I get

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Coming from the `kind` key. Any idea on what could be going on?

Comment: Your JSON has null value for `ofType` in some elements: `phoneCountry`, `phoneNumber` and `address`.

Comment: Damn, didnt notice that in the sea of data. If I replace `null` with, for example `"Null"` should it work?

Comment: No because you are doing `["kind"]` on it, it has to be a dictionary. Try using `get` which allows you to give a default value if the item is not found. Check my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three elements in your JSON data that have `ofType` value null. This causes to fail when trying to do `None["kind"]`. To manage this kind of cases you can use `get` and give an empty dict as default value.

```
specificType_type_ofType_kinds = [f['type'].get('ofType', {}).get('kind') for f in specificTypeJson['data']['__type']['fields']]
```

EDIT:
this works if the key is not present, whereas if the value is `null` you need to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here (7th and 8th objects from the end):

```
    {
        "description": "",
        "name": "phoneNumber",
        "type": {
            "kind": "SCALAR",
            "ofType": null
        }
    },
    {
        "description": "",
        "name": "phoneCountry",
        "type": {
            "kind": "SCALAR",
            "ofType": null
        }
    }
```

Since you have the ofType field to null, that becomes None when you read the JSON, and when you try to access the 'kind' property, it fails.
You can check it by doing this:

```
[f["type"]["ofType"]!=None for f in specificTypeJson['data']['__type']['fields']]
```